# Using Lag on date logged in data to work out time between logins

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, lag

I have a dataset which I will simplify to:

from str()
$ User_id     : num [1:84164] ####### ####### ####### (anonymized) ...
$ DateLoggedIn: Date[1:84164], format: "2020-11-14" "2020-11-11" "2020-11-05" "2020-11-01" ...

I am trying to create a dataframe that has a range of columns for when logged in.

User_id | DateLoggedIn (ordered to last) | Second last login | Third last login | and so on so that I can work out the time between all of the columns and can also create an average time between logins column.

```
TimeBetween <- TimeBetween >% arrange(.,User_id, desc(DateLoggedIn)) %>% group_by(.,User_id)  %>% 
  mutate(.,SecLog = lag(DateLoggedIn,1)) %>% 
  mutate(.,TrdLog = lag(DateLoggedIn,2)) %>% 
  mutate(.,FrthLog = lag(DateLoggedIn,3)) %>% 
  mutate(.,FithLog = lag(DateLoggedIn,4)) %>%
```

The output of this is always wrong I am expecting it to lag for each userID but it only lags from the first row.

I have tried using HMISC lag \ DPLYR last \ base lag as well as changing the order of the pipes and inner arrange order to no luck.

Can anybody help please?

Thanks!

Example Data   --   dput(TimeBetween[1:50, c(1, 3, 6)])
structure(list(User_id = c(130223, 130223, 130223,130223,130223,130223,136038,136038,136038), DateLoggedIn = c("2020-11-14", "2020-11-11", "2020-11-05","2020-11-01","2020-10-28","2020-10-27","2020-09-21","2020-09-20","2020-09-20")

OR

User_id
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
142267
142267
142267
142267
142267
142267
142267
142267

DateLoggedIn
2020-11-14
2020-11-11
2020-11-05
2020-11-01
2020-10-28
2020-10-27
2020-10-26
2020-10-23
2020-10-22
2020-10-21
2020-10-11
2020-09-11
2020-09-08
2020-09-07
2020-09-06
2020-09-05
2020-09-02
2020-08-30
2020-08-29

Desired Output - For each user id the lag starts again.

User_id
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
144548
142267
142267
142267
142267
142267
142267
142267
142267

DateLoggedIn
2020-11-14
2020-11-11
2020-11-05
2020-11-01
2020-10-28
2020-10-27
2020-10-26
2020-10-23
2020-10-22
2020-10-21
2020-10-11
2020-09-11
2020-09-08
2020-09-07
2020-09-06
2020-09-05
2020-09-02
2020-08-30
2020-08-29

Lag1
NA
2020-11-14
2020-11-11
2020-11-05
2020-11-01
2020-10-28
2020-10-27
2020-10-26
2020-10-23
2020-10-22
2020-10-21
NA
2020-09-11
2020-09-08
2020-09-07
2020-09-06
2020-09-05
2020-09-02
2020-08-30

Lag2
NA
NA
2020-11-14
2020-11-11
2020-11-05
2020-11-01
2020-10-28
2020-10-27
2020-10-26
2020-10-23
2020-10-22
NA
NA
2020-09-11
2020-09-08
2020-09-07
2020-09-06
2020-09-05
2020-09-02

Lag3
NA
NA
NA
2020-11-14
2020-11-11
2020-11-05
2020-11-01
2020-10-28
2020-10-27
2020-10-26
2020-10-23
NA
NA
NA
2020-09-11
2020-09-08
2020-09-07
2020-09-06
2020-09-05

However what I am getting is lag doesn't distinguish between different user ids.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully better now

Answer (score 0):

After fixing a few typos, I can't reproduce your issue.

```
library(dplyr)
TimeBetween <- structure(list(User_id = c(130223, 130223, 130223,130223,130223,130223,136038,136038,136038), 
                           DateLoggedIn = c("2020-11-14", "2020-11-11", "2020-11-05","2020-11-01","2020-10-28","2020-10-27","2020-09-21","2020-09-20","2020-09-20")))

TimeBetween <- bind_cols(TimeBetween)
# TimeBetween$DateLoggedIn <- as.Date(TimeBetween$DateLoggedIn )

TimeBetween %>% arrange(User_id, desc(DateLoggedIn)) %>% group_by(User_id)  %>% 
mutate(SecLog = lag(DateLoggedIn,1)) %>% 
   mutate(TrdLog = lag(DateLoggedIn,2)) %>% 
   mutate(FrthLog = lag(DateLoggedIn,3)) %>% 
   mutate(FithLog = lag(DateLoggedIn,4))

# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   User_id [2]
  User_id DateLoggedIn SecLog     TrdLog     FrthLog    FithLog   
    <dbl> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1  130223 2020-11-14   NA         NA         NA         NA        
2  130223 2020-11-11   2020-11-14 NA         NA         NA        
3  130223 2020-11-05   2020-11-11 2020-11-14 NA         NA        
4  130223 2020-11-01   2020-11-05 2020-11-11 2020-11-14 NA        
5  130223 2020-10-28   2020-11-01 2020-11-05 2020-11-11 2020-11-14
6  130223 2020-10-27   2020-10-28 2020-11-01 2020-11-05 2020-11-11
7  136038 2020-09-21   NA         NA         NA         NA        
8  136038 2020-09-20   2020-09-21 NA         NA         NA        
9  136038 2020-09-20   2020-09-20 2020-09-21 NA         NA
```

Asking to close this question.

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't work for me. I tried it as both date and character. Is there a reason you had the date as chr and not date?

I will investigate further

Comment: On running the code on a blank project it works so. The problem seems to be to do with a package clash. Thanks for your help